# Graded tensor product of rings in Künneth formula

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I'd expect $$H^*(S^3 \times S^1,\mathbb{Z})=H^*(S^3)\otimes H^*(S^1)=[\mathbb{Z}<1>\oplus0\oplus0\oplus\mathbb{Z}<x>]\otimes[\mathbb{Z}<1>\oplus\mathbb{Z}<y>]=\mathbb{Z}<1>\oplus\mathbb{Z}<1\otimes y>\oplus0\oplus\mathbb{Z}<x\otimes 1>\oplus\mathbb{Z}<x\otimes y>=\mathbb{Z}[x]/_{(x^2)}\otimes\mathbb{Z}[y]/_{(y^2)}=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/_{(x^2,y^2)},$$ however I saw in a book that it is $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/_{(x^2,y^2,xy+yx)}.$

Here on math.stackexchange I learned that tensor product in the isomorphism from Künneth formula is supposed to be graded tensor product. So my question is - how do I calculate graded tensor product? For example, to get the right answer above. This page https://planetmath.org/gradedtensorproduct says that the grading is same as in regular tensor product, so I guess additively the answer still must look like $\mathbb{Z}<1>\oplus\mathbb{Z}<y>\oplus0\oplus\mathbb{Z}<x>\oplus\mathbb{Z}<x\otimes y>$. Where do I get $(xy+yx)$ from though?

Thanks.

Comment: A basic property of the cup product is that $yx = (-1)^{|x| |y|} xy$ for any cohomology classes $x$ and $y$, where $|x|$ means the dimension of $x$.

Comment: What book are you using @Haldot?

Comment: @Brain Sorry, I don't remember. Chances are that it was some russian book on algebraic topology. May be "Elements of Homology Theory" by Prasolov, but I really am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result cannot be correct, as $xy = yx \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, so that $xy + yx = 2xy$, and you cannot expect a 2-torsion element in the top cohomology of your space. The issue is that Künneth formula is an isomorphism of graded rings.

You are correct that $H^\bullet(S^3 \times S^1, \mathbb{Z}) \cong H^\bullet(S^3, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^\bullet(S^1,\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)\otimes\mathbb{Z}[x]/(y^2)$. However, the last tensor product is graded, so that 
$$
x \otimes y = (-1)^{\deg x\deg y}y\otimes x = (-1)^{3\cdot 1}y\otimes x = - y\otimes x
$$
Therefore, if you wish to identify $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2)\otimes\mathbb{Z}[x]/(y^2)$ with a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ you need to impose the additional relation $xy = -yx$ or, in other words $xy + yx = 0$.

Comment: Ok, I think, I got it.
Just another example:
$H^*(S^3 \times S^4,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}<1>\oplus0\oplus0\oplus\mathbb{Z}<x\otimes 1>\oplus\mathbb{Z}<1\otimes y>\oplus0\oplus0\oplus\mathbb{Z}<x\otimes y>=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/{(x^2,y^2,xy+yx)}$ again, right? So, this ring is isomorphic to $H^*(S^3 \times S^1,\mathbb{Z})$ as a ring, but not as a graded ring.

Comment: Aren't both isomorhic to $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/_{(x^2,y^2,xy+yx)}$ as rings?

Comment: Ohhh, I misread completely! Yes, you're correct, the only difference lies in the grading.

Comment: Actually, wait for a second. 
$$x\otimes y=(-1)^{\deg x \deg y}y \otimes x=(-1)^{3 \cdot 4} y \otimes x=y \otimes x,$$ so still $$H^*(S^3 \times S^4,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/_{(x^2,y^2)},$$ right? And this answer will always be true for product of 2 spheres, where one or both of them have even dimension.

Comment: Indeed. i’m sorry i confused signs.